# How to use the Xpath and CSS selector in for function

Tags: python, html, css, xpath

I am a rookie, and want use the scrapy framework to grab something, but I have trouble:

Html A:

```
<ul class="tip" id="tip1">
    <li id="tip1_0">
        <a href="http://***" title="***" target="_self">***
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="tip1_1">
        <a href="http://***" title="***" target="_self">***
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="tip1_2">
        <a href="http://***" title="***" target="_self">***
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use:

```
f = response.xpath("//*[@id='tip1']//li/a/@href | //*[@id='tip1']//li/a/@title").extract()
```

When I get the f is a list, and i will change the list(f) to dict(name0=f[0], value0=f[1], name1=f[2], value1=[f3], and so on). Is any way to more easy?

Html B:

```
<div class="info">
    <a target="_blank" href="***" title="***">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <a target="_blank" href="***" title="***">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <a target="_blank" href="***" title="***">
    </a>
</div>
```

In this case:

```
file = response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]')
for line in file:
    f = line.xpath('/a/@href').extract()
    d = line.xpath('/a/@title').extract()
```

But, It do not work, just return 'f = []' and 'd =[]', So， i was confuse, and how can I slove this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have made your inner expressions context-specific by prepending dots:

```
f = line.xpath('./a/@href').extract()
d = line.xpath('./a/@title').extract()
```

Or, point your outer expression to `a` and get the `@href` and `@title`:

```
file = response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]/a')
for line in file:
    f = line.xpath('@href').extract_first()
    d = line.xpath('@title').extract_first()
```

Also note the use of `extract_first()` method.